# Node.js detach a spawned child after spawing

Tags: node.js, spawn, child-process

I am redirecting the stderr stream of a `detached` `child_process` to a file, using

```
fd = fs.openSync('./err.log', 'a');
```

and passing this fd as stderr in the `spawn`.

I am looking for a way to intercept data written to the file. meaning, when that child process writes something, I want to process it before writing to the file.

I tried making a writable stream and giving it instead of file descriptor to spawn. but that didn't help.

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve that?

Also, can I spawn a child_process normally (`detached = false`) and listen on `data` event of `child.stdout` and when I am ready, I can detach the child. So basically, I want some initial data from `child_process` and then let it run as background process and terminate the parent.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [Transform stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1).

Here is a possible solution for your problem:

```
var child = spawn( /* whatever options */ )
var errFile = fs.createWriteStream('err.log', { flags: 'w' })
var processErrors = new stream.Transform()
processErrors._transform = function (data, encoding, done) {
  // Do what you want with the data here.
  // data is most likely a Buffer object
  // When you're done, send the data to the output of the stream:
  this.push(data)
  done() // we're done processing this chunk of data
}
processErrors._flush = function(done) {
  // called at the end, when no more data will be provided
  done()
}

child.stderr.pipe(processErrors).pipe(f)
```

Note the way we pipe streams: the stderr is a Readable stream, the processErrors is a Transform stream which is Duplex, and f is a Writable stream only. The processErrors stream will process the data and output it as it has received it (thus looking like a [PassThrough](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream with your business internal logic on the inside).

Comment: This allows intercepting the data before writing to the file. However, I want to detach that child after I get some success confirmation from the child.

Comment: I can't detach a child till it uses the parents `stdout` and `stderr`. basically I wan't to set `stdio: ['ignore', out, err]` while spawing the child so I can `child.unref()` and parent process can exit.

Comment: In this case this is tricky, since you can't even remove the processErros stream (unpipe stderr from it and re-pipe it to f), since f is still managed by Node you won't be able detach it…

Comment: How about creating another child process that will execute `tail -f` on your output file, then piping this child's output to the Transform stream? When you get the data you want, you can kill tail and detach your original child. Hacky, but should work if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: hmmm.. It will some what solve the problem, but still not exactly what I wanted..